# Why is $\int 1/(t ~\log^2 t) ~dt$ convergent?

Tags: integration

$\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{t} dt = \ln t$ diverges.

How do I show that $\displaystyle \int_2^\infty \frac{1}{t ~\log^2 t} dt$ is convergent?

Comment: Hint: let $u=\log t$. (For the integral from $2$ to $\infty$, say.)

Comment: And, you do need limits on those integrals in order for your question to make sense...

Comment: If you don't write down any limits for your integral there is no meaning to "divergent", "convergent"

Comment: On what interval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help yourself figure out the appropriate substitution, reorganize the integral into:
$$ \int \frac{1}{\log^2 t} \frac{dt}{t} $$
Does this ring a bell? $\dfrac{dt}{t}$? If we take $u = \log t,$ then we have $du = \dfrac{dt}{t}$ and $\dfrac{1}{\log^2 t} = \dfrac{1}{u^2}.$
So the integral is:
$$ \int \frac{1}{t\log^2 t} dt = \int \frac{1}{u^2} du = - \frac{1}{u} + \text{const} = -\frac{1}{\log t} + \text{const}.$$
Now $$ \int_2^{\infty} \frac{1}{t\log^2 t} dt = - \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\log n} +  \frac{1}{\log 2} = 0 + \frac{1}{\log 2}.$$

Comment: Did you guess the integral's limits?